# Spool command in Unix printing error

Tags: database, unix, oracle11g

I am trying the generate output in csv file using spool command after querying database, but the output contains ¿? so that the value is either printed in next column or next tab

```
SET echo OFF
SET feedback OFF
SET heading off
SET linesize 400
SET pagesize 0
SET newpage 0
SET TAB OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
spool data.csv

select * from employee ;
spool off;
EOF
```

Employee table

```
ename id address 
ram    2  hyd,india
syam   3  ban,india
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what should appear where I've put the `¿?` mark, or otherwise clarify the content.  It really isn't clear what the problem is.  You claim you're getting an error, but you don't show the error message.  This is unanswerable as written.  Flag this comment as 'no longer needed' when you've fixed the question.

Comment: The *only* commas in your output are coming from the address values, so all the rows without ay commas in that DB column will appear in a single column in Excel, and those that do have a comma in the address will be split. Start by looking at the output file in a plain text editor and think about how it *should* be delimited. There are lots of questions about creating CSV from Oracle.